# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - handling all exceptions with an error page

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core (2.2) app, and I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the generic "An error occured...." message that shows very specific deatils about the error or even the stack trace and line numbers in my code.

Both upon starting up the app and any time later in the app.

I thought I could use:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

and any unhandled exceptions will be caught by the middleware and then the user will be sent to my Home controller and Error view.

But this doesn't happen.

I forced errors to occur in my Startup.cs and later on in some of my Razor Pages, and I either see a blank page or I still see the very descriptive error page with error details and stack trace. Which I of course do not want in production.

Am I misunderstanding how this middleware works and how to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Those detailed error messages only show in a development environment, checkout the Configure method in `Startup.cs` file. You could add an else to the env check for your custom ExceptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

Basically, asp.net core `Configure` method has following middleware by default

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{//for production
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

}
```

And you will find the `Error.cshtml` in `Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` which only shows the RequestId without detailed inforamtion in production by default.

If you want to use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");` in development mode for a test, then just remove the above if/else block and use the code directly, then it will direct you to the error page in development.